# Mysql slow queries wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wpml

My hosting provider wants to suspend website due to slow queries. Here are they:

```
Time running : 34
Query : 
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    wp_posts.ID
FROM
    wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id
        AND t.element_type LIKE 'post\_%'
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_icl_languages l ON t.language_code = l.code
        AND l.active = 1
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Europe%')
        OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%Europe%')
        OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Europe%')))
        AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post' , 'page',
        'attachment',
        'slides',
        'careers',
        'partners',
        'team',
        'news',
        'casestudies')
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        OR wp_posts.post_author = 1
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
        AND (t.language_code = 'en'
        OR t.language_code IS NULL)
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Europe%' DESC , wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10

Time running : 50
Query : 
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    wp_posts.ID
FROM
    wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id
        AND t.element_type LIKE 'post\_%'
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_icl_languages l ON t.language_code = l.code
        AND l.active = 1
WHERE
    1 = 1
        AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%1%')
        OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%1%')
        OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%1%')))
        AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')
        AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post' , 'page',
        'attachment',
        'slides',
        'careers',
        'partners',
        'team',
        'news',
        'casestudies',
        'privatearea')
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
        AND (t.language_code = 'en'
        OR t.language_code IS NULL)
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%1%' DESC , wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

How I see this query had been executed after using search form in website, right ? How can I solve this issue ? (also I have WPML plugin installed)

Comment: implement `indexing` on the fields which you are using in where condition and in joining.

Comment: I don't know from where this query is coming from ? @urfusion

Comment: You need to implement indexing on your tables. So open your `phpmyadmin`  go to that table and apply `indexing` on those fields.

Comment: This is problem with full text search and there is no easy solution. The construction `LIKE '%something%'` is very slow and using indexes won't help.

Comment: so do you know any solution ? because my host wants to suspend my account, I made search hidden for now, but I need search actaully @Michas

Comment: @aidaghazaryan 1. Read about Full Text Search in MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html 2. Write code to use it or find different plugin.